# How to active on scroll the same function as on click and change the color of the each different section

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, background

I have a click function which is working to add a class "active" but I want to make it work with the scroll aswell.

Another thing is I have a lighthouse background image and I want to make it full height and go down when I change section. I also want the color of each section to change.

Just as on this wireframe : https://xd.adobe.com/view/b04dbb17-5fd9-426d-a02b-6eb9c99bb2e3-e51e/screen/5f938c4d-2f84-467c-8bdb-c0a41f1cc13f?fullscreen

You'll find the code below.

**HMTL**
I have 6 sections and I want each section to be a part of the lighthouse

```
    <div class="section" id="home">
     
    
    <nav class="lader" id="cssmenu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#home" class="active" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <span class="circle"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#services" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <span class="circle"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#valeurs" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <span class="circle"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#missions" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <span class="circle"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#section5" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <span class="circle"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#footer" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <span class="circle"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="services"></div>
    <div class="section" id="valeurs"></div>
    <div class="section" id="missions"></div>
    <div class="section" id="sections5"></div>
    <div class="section" id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**
I also want the color of the section to change

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0; 
}

    body {
      background-image: url("https://montaigne-energie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/phare_blan3.svg");
      background-position: 50% 2%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 140% auto;
      background-attachment: local;
    }
    
    #home {
      background-color: rgba(182, 166, 128, 0.8);
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #services {
      background-color: rgb(33, 59, 82,.8);
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #valeurs {
    background-color: rgba(182, 166, 128, 0.8);
    height: 100%;
    
    }
    
    #missions {
      background-color: rgb(33, 59, 82,.8);
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #section5 {
      background-color: rgba(182, 166, 128, 0.8);
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #footer {
      background-color: rgb(33, 59, 82,.8);
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .section{
    min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 35%;
      right: 2%;
      bottom: auto;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .lader ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .lader li {
      padding: 15px 0;
    }
    
    .lader span {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .circle {
      height: 13px;
      width: 13px;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid white;
      background-color: none;
    }
    
    .lader a.active span {
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    nav a:hover span {
      background-color: #fff;
      transition: 300ms;
    }
```

**JQUERY**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    function myFunction(tag) {
      $("#cssmenu a.active").removeClass("active"); //remove previous li active class
      $(tag).closest("a").addClass("active");
    }
```